# Obter URI de uma full size foto pela Camera no OnActivityResult

Tags: java, android, android-camera

Estou usando a câmera do Android para tirar foto e salvá-la a partir de um WebService. Consegui fazer isso, porém usando o método de pegar uma thumbnail. A minha intenção é pegar a imagem em full size.

Pesquisei muito e cheguei até o site oficial do Android.
http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath

Sendo assim, no meu botão de tirar a foto chamei o método dispatchTakePictureIntent, como tem no site oficial e também criei o método createImageFile(), como será mostrado abaixo.

```
static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            ...
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}

String mCurrentPhotoPath;

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
        imageFileName,  /* prefix */
        ".jpg",         /* suffix */
        storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

Tranquilo. Porém a minha intenção agora é pegar o resultado no OnActivityResult e, seguindo o tutorial oficial da google, não ficou claro pra mim qual o código eu boto no OnActivityResult (o código que tem lá do activityresult é pra thumbnail.

Vi alguns códigos na internet, porém muitos pegam a thumbnail do URI. Quero pegar no OnActivityResult ela full.

Vi os métodos setPic e galleryAddPic no site, mas não sei onde vou aplicar.

Alguém pode ajudar qual código insiro no OnActivityResult?

Comment: Não entendo a sua pergunta porque o *URI* para a foto tirada é aquele que você passou aqui `takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));`